# Is there a 'rowspan' or 'merge two table cells to single table cell' function for pandas tables/dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a table with some values spanning over two rows, but I can't find any solution. I have appended two images of what I got from pandas and how I want it to look like.

[output from pandas:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0eG8.png)

[target table form:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aEG0.jpg)

Here is the code of my testing:

```
import pandas as pd

dict = {'index': [('LCS', 'sequence1'),('LCS', 'sequence2')],
        'columns': ['alignment', 'score', 'pathcoordinates'],
        'data': [['AAAGT', '', ''], ['GGTAC', 5, '[4,5] -> [5,5]']],
        'index_names': ['', ''],
        'column_names': [''],
        }

df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict, orient='tight')
```

Comment: Pandas doesn't do merged cells.

Comment: No.  Remember that a pandas table is just a collection of columns, where each column is an independent numpy array.  There's no relationship between the rows, or the columns.  If you need it printed in a certain way, then you are free to do whatever you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas doesn't really do merged cells (as some have already commented); although, index columns do get grouped together:

```py
data={'index': [('LCS', 'sequence1'), ('LCS', 'sequence2')], 'columns': ['alignment', 'score', 'pathcoordinates'], 'data': [['AAAGT', 5, '[4,5] -> [5,5]'], ['GGTAC', 5, '[4,5] -> [5,5]']], 'index_names': ['', 'sequence'], 'column_names': ['']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='tight')
df2 = df1.reset_index().set_index(['', 'score', 'pathcoordinates', 'sequence'])
```

| `df1` |  | `df2` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image: df1] | **⇨** | [image: df2] |

and [`.to_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) will output those grouped labels as merged cells, even though most other writer methods wouldn't:

| Output Type | Example |
| --- | --- |
| Excel | [image: xlsx_op] |
| Markdown | [image: md_op] |
| CSV | [image: csv_op] |